# Having problems with tkinter scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, scrollbar

So yeah, I just want a scrollbars cause I have a lot of frames, but I just don't get how to use it.
I tried a couple of things with a little variation each time but even though I think I'm getting close it's still not there.

In my code I have a canvas that fills the main Tk window and inside that canvas I have a lot of frames in a grid generated with a for loop.

Code:

```py
import tkinter as to
import tkinter.ttk

def generateFrames(root, o):
    pieFrame = Frame(root)
    pieFrame.grid(row=int(o/4), column=o%4, padx=25)

mainWindow = tk.Tk()
scrollbar = Scrollbar(mainWindow, orient='vertical')
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
canvas = Canvas(mainWindow, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
canvas.pack(expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)

for I in range(16):
    generateFrames(canvas, i)

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: For one, you have to call the `set` method on an instance of `Scrollbar` rather than on the class itself.

Comment: That's actually autocorrect... I'm using a phone, the actual code has correct syntax.

Comment: We can only see the code posted in the question.

Comment: Yeah I know, I'm very sorry about that, and if course you were right. But that's not actually the problem, just a typo in this case. Do you see anything else wrong with the code, or maybe if you have a snippet of a working code could you let me try that? I do appreciate the help though dont get me wrong.

Comment: You have to configure the `scrollregion` attribute of the canvas.

Comment: You need to create an internal frame and put in canvas using `.create_window(...)`. Then put those frames inside this internal frame instead.  You also need to specify the size of those frames, otherwise they will be zero size.  Update `scrollregion` option of canvas as well.

Comment: thank you very much, both of you. using an internal frame and `scrollregion` did the trick, though i forgot to mention the frames are not empty so i didnt need to specify the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working code is:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk

def generateFrames(root, o):
    pieFrame = Frame(root)
    pieFrame.grid(row=int(o/4), column=o%4, padx=25)

mainWindow = tk.Tk()
scrollbar = Scrollbar(mainWindow, orient='vertical')
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
canvas = Canvas(mainWindow, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
canvas.pack(expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)
canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0,0,0,2000))

mainFrame = Frame(mainWindow)
mainFrame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)

for I in range(16):
    generateFrames(mainFrame, i)

canvas.create_window(950, 750, window=mainFrame)

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Better make `mainFrame` child of `canvas` instead of `mainWindow`.  `mainFrame.pack(...)` is not necessary.  BTW your code does not run because missing prefix `tk.` on `Scollbar(...)`, `Canvas(...)`, etc.  Also `I` should be `i` in `for I in range(16)`.